# Split array by rows

Tags: python, split

I have a very basic problem.I have wrote a code which  open a .txt file which contain a numbers  `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.Then it square all of it and write to other file.
Right now I want to add to this code procedure which split all of this numbers in rows and rewrite,like this:

```
1 4 9
16 25 36
49 64 81
```

My code already:

```
n=[]
dane = open("num.txt", "r")

for i in dane:
  i = i.replace('\n','')
  for j in i.split(' '):
        j = int(j)
        j = j**2
        n.append(j)

nowy = open("newnum.txt","w")
nowy.write(str(n))
nowy.close()
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the code?

Comment: how your actual input looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have written works fine expect for the writing part. For which you need to change the last three lines of code as

```
nowy = open("newnum.txt","w")
for i in range(0,len(n),3):
    nowy.write("{} {} {}\n".format(n[i],n[i+1],n[i+2]))
nowy.close()
```

The `for` loop can be explained as,

- loop through the list `n` that you have generated 3 at a time by using the third argument to the `range` function which is called step.
- write out the values three at a time into the file, terminated by the newline character

The output after changing the lines of code is as expected

```
1 4 9
16 25 36
49 64 81
```

Ref:

- [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)
- [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: @wiedzminYo All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @Bhargav's answer, [according to the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#zip) *"[a] possible idiom for clustering a data series into n-length groups [is] using `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`"*

You can use the *star* to unpack a list/tuple as arguments to `format` function call too.

All this will lead to a more Pythonic (or, rather crypto-Pythonic ?) version of the writing part:

```
with open("newnum.txt","w") as nowy:
    for sublist in zip(*[iter(n)]*3):
        nowy.write("{} {} {}\n".format(*sublist))
```

Please note the use of a context manager (`with` statement) to ensure proper closing of the file *in all cases* when exiting from the block. As other changes would be subject to discussion, that later is a *must* -- and you should definitively take the habit of using it
<sub>(BTW, have you noticed you never closed the `dane` file? A simple mistake that would have been avoided by the use of a context manager to manage that resource...)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
strNew = ''
dane = open("num.txt", "r")
row = 0
for i in dane:
  i = i.replace('\n','')
  for j in i.split(' '):
    row += 1
    j = int(j)
    j = j**2
    if (row % 3) == 0:
        strNew += str(j)+'\n'
    else:
        strNew += str(j) + ' ' # it can be ' ' or '\t'

nowy = open("newnum.txt","w")
nowy.write(strNew)
nowy.close()
```

The result is:

```
1 4 9
16 25 36
49 64 81
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=[]
dane = open("num.txt", "r")

for i in dane:
  i = i.replace('\n','')
  for j in i.split(' '):
        j = int(j)
        j = j**2
        # new code added
        # why str(j)? Because array in Python can only have one type of element such as string, int, etc. as opposed to tuple that can have multiple type in itself. I appended string because I wanna append \n at the end of each step(in outer loop I mean)
        n.append(str(j))

  # new code added
  n.append("\n")

nowy = open("newnum.txt","w")
nowy.write(str(n))
nowy.close()
```

Comment: "array in Python can only have one type of element". `n` is a Python list; Python doesn't have a native array type (although a Python list is implemented in CPython as an array of pointers). The elements of a Python list _do not_ have to be of the same type.  However, it's generally considered good programing style to avoid mixing types in a list (apart from special values like `None`), but that's a guideline, not a hard & fast rule.